# repeating effect "show elements on click" with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im wondering.. i wrote this little piece of code to show an element when clicking a link in the webpage.. it works perfectly fine.. the question is.. i need to use the effect more than once with other divs and ids
 This is my code.. if i want to reuse it.. do i need to write the code over and over again and change only the ids or is there another way?

```
$(document).ready(
        function(){
        $("#frueh").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".carta ,#fruehstueck, #fruehstueck2").toggle("slow");
        });
    });
```

Comment: You can create a function and put the code in there instead. Then you just have to call the function where/whenever you want execute the same logic. Learn  more about functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html.

Comment: You could give a class to the items that will be clicked. Then, when an item of the class is clicked it will run this code. Right now you have it restricted to an id. You are talking about the clickable item, right? If not then creating a function is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array in which you push all needed selectors when you need to

```
var selectors = [".carta ,#fruehstueck, #fruehstueck2"];

$(function(){
    $("#frueh").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(selectors.join(',')).toggle("slow");
    });
});
// then later ..
selectors.push('#foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".carta ,#fruehstueck, #fruehstueck2").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggle("slow");
    });
});
```